# Good speech recognition engine for Mac, not iOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, speech-recognition

Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I didn't see it anywhere.

I'm working on a Mac program that will take voice commands, and `NSSpeechRecognizer` isn't quite doing it for me.

I want something a little more dynamic so I can set *alarms*, *make dates*, *give more natural commands*, etc.

Every open source speech engine I've found is tailored toward iOS. Do openears/vocalkit etc. still work just as fine for Mac programs?

Comment: You might as well wait for Mountain Lion and hope that apple releases a Dictation API for developers.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: But that will probably be backed by Apple's Siri service and require an Internet connection (and you cannot use it if you work at IBM). I am assuming that OP is asking for something that works locally.

Comment: I don't believe they mentioned anything about adding Siri to Mountain Lion in WWDC, just bringing the ability to go from speech to text (aka the Dictation feature in all textboxes).

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer speech to text is done by the same service that does Siri. It's not done locally.

Comment: Even if they did put out a dictation API I doubt that would fit my needs best. Has anyone tried pocketsphinx on a cocoa app? Or is it bounded to cocoa touch?

Answer (score 3):

Speech recognition is exceptionally non-trivial. The engines that are free are free for a reason. If you expect dictation in any amount (like an alarm label), you're out of luck. There are reasons Siri requires an entire data center. The open source packages available won't get you much further than simple telephone auto-attendants.

Unless you have an extensive statistics background and free time, I'd recommend that you pursue licensing a commercial library or server implementation.

Comment: Pestilence is right.  I'll also add that the dynamic functionality you need should be considered against two different factors: 1. Speech Recognition & 2. Natural Language Processing Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

pocket sphinx from Carnegie Melon is about the only option

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/